# Convert DotNetZip ZipFile to byte array

Tags: vb.net, dotnetzip

I've built a DotNetZip ZipFile with several entries.  I'd like to convert it to a byte array so I can download it using the download construct below.

```
   Using wrkZip As New ZipFile
        '----- create zip, add memory stream----------
       For n As Integer = 0 To wrkAr.Count - 1
           wrkFS = wrkAr(n)
           wrkZip.AddEntry(wrkFS.FileName, wrkFS.ContentStream)
       Next

   dim wrkBytes() as Byte
   dim wrkFileName as string = "Test.txt"

   ===> wrkBytes = ConvertToByteArray(wrkZip) <==== 

    context.Response.Clear()
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & wrkFileName)
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(wrkBytes)
        wrkBytesInStream = Nothing
        context.Response.End()
```

I recognize that there is a ZipFile method for this:

```
wrkZip.Save(context.Response.OutputStream)
```

However, I've got a difficult bug in using that, described here:

[DotNetZip download works in one site, not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925639/dotnetzip-download-works-in-one-site-not-another)

so I'm looking for a short term workaround. The short story on the bug is that the the ZipFile writes to disk fine, and downloads fine in a very similar website;  it just doesn't work in the case I need it to right now.

So, how to convert a DotNetZip ZipFile to a byte array?  I've looked at other answers however they don't describe this particular case of converting a whole, loaded ZipFile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the contents into a byte array:

```
Dim ms as New MemoryStream
wrkZip.Save(ms)
wrkBytes = ms.ToArray()
```

Comment: That worked.   Didn't solve the download problem, but answered the question, and eliminated ZipFile.Save(to page context) as the download problem.  Thanks!